# Can I propose a talk in a seminar on a research paper which is under communication in a journal?

Tags: mathematics, conference, presentation, seminars

I have communicated one research paper of mathematics in a journal. Now I want to talk on that paper in a seminar/conference just for a presentation and getting a presentation certificate (probably), but not for publication.

Is it ethical ?

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfectly ethical. You are discussing your own ideas. Even in the case that the journal already has copyright to your paper (probably not here), that doesn't mean that they somehow "own" the ideas.

Even if your remarks were published, it would be fine, though some journals object to prepublication of the paper. But that only applies to the paper - the specific expression of the ideas - not the ideas themselves.

The "certificate" is irrelevant to the ethical question here. Good for you if you get it, but the action is ethical in any case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I am a PhD student and there is a rule in my country, that I should present at least 2 seminars. Second, possibly the certificate (if they provide) will increase my CV.

Comment: I mean that the certificate is irrelevant to the ethical question.

Comment: ok, thanks. I got it

Answer (score 2):

Presenting your results at a seminar is not a violation of any ethical academic norm. Conferences are slightly different: you should find out whether the conference will have a published proceedings.

If your work will be peer-reviewed and published as part of the conference proceedings this may violate the journal's publication policy. In particular, you won't be able to authorize the journal to publish the work as that privilege has already been given to whatever conference you had given it to by letting your paper be part of a published proceedings (you will need to actually sign this when you publish).

Normally, these are questions you can just ask the conference organizers and they'll be happy to let you know how to proceed. Some conferences allow the publication of an abstract/short paper that just summarizes the results, and thus does not constitute a violation of most journal policies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer